# if($_FILES['files']['name']!="") run if files, don't run if no files headache

Tags: php, file-upload, if-statement

Not having any luck with my other thread with specific code so if I can I'd like to ask how people would go about getting this to work.

I have an page where my client edits details of a property displayed on a property list, say they edit text and don't add any images to this property.

HTML form works fine, I'm just looking at the php.

Example:

```
If files selected then run this script as an include
If no files selected then exit
```

Something like this...

```
if($_FILES['files']['name']!="")
 {
 Do this
 }
  else
{
exit();
}
```

I'm going mental trying to figure this out so any help or suggestions would be great. I have tried a few variations and variations on top of those variations and nothing seems to work so far.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isset()` or`empty()` constructs. (For more information read PHP doc)

```
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name']))
 {
  //
 }
```

Comment: LEGEND! worked perfectly. Thanks AVD.

@xdazz cheers for the edit did see the `$_` missing ;)